# Django - Ajax POST JS variables to initialize form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am working on a django project in which I have gathered up all of my variables in js and am trying to initialize a form (inside a modal popup) on same page without any refresh. I have the form showing up inside my modal, but can't quite figure out the Ajax post method to get my js variables into the initial form fields. Any help would be much appreciated!

index.html - this function fires where I need it, but returns the page url instead of the data object I am trying to define.

**Index.html**

```
 $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: '',
                data: {
                    geology: ('#geology').value,
                    latitude: ('latitude').value,
                    longitude: ('longitude').value,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',   
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data.geology); 
                },
                error: function(error_data){
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(error_data);
                }
            });
```

**views.py**

```
def home_view(request):


    geology = request.GET.get('geology')
    latitude = request.GET.get('latitude')
    longitude = request.GET.get('longitude')
    form = MineralForm(initial={'mineral': mineral, 'geology': geology, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': "INITIAL", 'description': description}) # populates form with what user tried to submit...
```

UPDATE:

Here is an update on where I am at:

The modal window opens after an api call to gather some geology data. I am hoping to populate this form with the geology data, without refreshing the page. I am using ajax to create a post that get's my data object over to views.py (I am able to print the data upon POST from views.py into the terminal) but the form is not initializing with the data. Instead, it is initializing with the "PRE_POST" values, even after the api call to gather the data and post via ajax.

Any thoughts on what might be going on here, or how to resolve would be much appreciated!

**matMap.html (snippets)**

```
<!-- mineralForm Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade draggable" id="mineralFormModal" role="dialog" style="height: 100%;">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button id ="mineralFormModalClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" align="center" style="font-family: Lobster">Add New Mineral</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mineralFormModal_body" id="mineralFormModal_body" style="position:absolute; top:0"> 
                    <h3>loading before modal clears</h3>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    {{ form }}


                    <br>
                    <button id="modalSave" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                    <div class="modal-footer red lighten-3">
                        <button id="modalClose" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div> 

            </div>

(...)

$.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '',
                    data: {

                        geology: geology,
                        latitude: x,
                        longitude: y,
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',   
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("AJAX POST SUCCESS!"); //grabs this entire page and all variables. 
                    },
                    error: function(error_data){
                        console.log("error");
                        console.log(error_data);
                    }


                });
```

**views.py**

```
def home_view(request):
    geology = request.POST.get('geology')
    latitude = request.POST.get('latitude')
    longitude = request.POST.get('longitude')

    if request.method == "POST":
        print("!!!! POSTING from HOME !!!!" + geology + " " + latitude + " " + longitude)
       form = MineralForm(request.POST, initial={'geology': "POST_VALUE",'latitude': "POST_VALUE", 'longitude': "POST_VALUE"})
        print("NOW WE ARE POSTING: ")
        print(form)
        return render(request, 'blog/matMap.html', {'form': form}) 

    else:
        print("LOADING HOME: INITIAL STATE (BEFORE POST)")
        form = MineralForm(initial={'geology': "PRE_POST",'latitude': 'PRE_POST', 'longitude': 'PRE_POST'}) # populates form with what user tried to submit...
        return render(request, 'blog/matMap.html', {'form': form})
```

And here is my terminal output, from initial page load through after the ajax post:

```
LOADING HOME: INITIAL STATE (BEFORE POST)
[13/Feb/2019 13:36:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 41261
Not Found: /js/scripts.js
[13/Feb/2019 13:36:07] "GET /js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3210
Not Found: /js/scripts.js
[13/Feb/2019 13:36:08] "GET /js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3210
[13/Feb/2019 13:36:08] "GET /api/chart/data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4039
!!!! POSTING from HOME !!!!Miocene -119.48709 44.85346
NOW WE ARE POSTING: 
<tr><th><label for="id_mineral">Mineral:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input type="text" name="mineral" required id="id_mineral"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_description">Description:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="10" required id="id_description">
</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_geology">Geology:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="geology" value="Miocene" required id="id_geology"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_latitude">Latitude:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="latitude" value="-119.48709" required id="id_latitude"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_longitude">Longitude:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="longitude" value="44.85346" required id="id_longitude"></td></tr>
[13/Feb/2019 13:36:30] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41593
```

However, even after this, when I call up my modal form, it looks like this:

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Does your `ajax` code run that `view`?

Comment: Yep! This ajax code runs in the home_view.

Comment: Then, you can not access body data by `request.GET`. I'll post answer how to change that.

Comment: I don't think `.value` is any method in jQuery it should be `.val()`. Also what is `latitude` and `longitude` are they classes ? also as you are sending data with a `POST` request so you need to get the same data with `POST` request in django so change `GET` to `POST`

Answer (score 1):

You're sending data via POST, so initialize your form with it:

`form = MineralForm(request.POST or None)`

Answer (score 0):

You can not access your `POST` body data by `request.GET`  use `request.POST`. And check [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)

```
def home_view(request):
    geology = request.POST.get('geology')
    latitude = request.POST.get('latitude')
    longitude = request.POST.get('longitude')
    form = MineralForm(initial={'mineral': mineral, 'geology': geology, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': "INITIAL", 'description': description}) # populates form with what user tried to submit...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses! I have the variables coming through the views.py now, and I am able to print them to my terminal. However, I still am not able to initialize the form with these values. I can initialize with a random string, for example "test", and that works fine. But when I try to use a variable the field comes out blank.

Comment: Please edit your question. Do not post your code in comment. @ramalamma

Comment: Did you check values in `request.POST` not empty? @ramalamma

Comment: thanks again for your multiple responses here. The post values are coming through. I put "if request.method == 'POST': print("POSTING: " + latitude + " " + longitude)" in my homeview. Sure enough, when I trigger the ajax call on my page, my terminal window shows "POSTING: 127.46 42.14".

Comment: Your view function is end without `return render(...)`? Please post your view code. I want to see all of view code. @ramalamma

Comment: Thank you for your post. I will update the original post to contain the full view. @Yongjin Jo